# full text search engine in hebrew

Tags: solr, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I want to try and use Elasticsearch as a full text search engine for a website in Hebrew.
I wanted to know if this Elasticsearch can produce good results for Hebrew and if there are any big websites in Israel that use it as their search engine.

If not ElasticSearch - maybe Apache Solr?
By the way - I'm using Ruby, but can work with Java as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [ICU plugin for Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/6.2/analysis-icu.html).

David.

Comment: Fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Solr seems to support Hebrew, see links to Language Analysers below:

- [Solr language analysis in Hebrew](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LanguageAnalysis#Hebrew)
- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ICUTokenizerFactory

Although I am not certain what the options for ElasticSearch are.

Comment: Solr uses the ICU project, exactly as the ICU plugin for elasticsearch does.

Answer (score 1):

Look at hebmorph - http://www.code972.com/blog/hebmorph/
It's a lucene plugin and we've been working with it in http://alpha.gov.il and http://www.guidestar.org.il/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Algolia](https://www.algolia.com/)

> By design the Algolia engine is language agnostic. Out of the box, it supports all languages / alphabets, including symbol based languages such as Chinese, Japanese and Korean.
>
> Additionally, Algolia handles multi-languages on the same website/app, meaning some users could search in French, and some in English, using the same Algolia account on the background.
>
> The purpose of this guide is to explain how to organize your indices to enable multi-language search.

Taken from [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/full-text-search/multi-language-search/multilingual-search/#before-starting)